# Using TAP with IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, ienumerable, blazor-server-side

I am updating my code to run asynchronously, but I'm running into issues because I am working with List<> and IEnumerable<> types. Everything I do gives me the same error: you cannot await Lists or IEnumerable<> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter.

Consider the following code:

```
var salesTask = GetSalesOpportunitiesAsync();

var opportunityTasks = new List<Task>
{
   salesTask // I've excluded the other tasks for this snippet.
};
    
while (opportunityTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task finishedTask = await WhenAny(opportunityTasks);
    opportunityTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
}

private async Task GetSalesOpportunitiesAsync()
{
    _sales = await (from opportunity in _opportunities
                   where opportunity.Stage.Name is "Prospect" or "Lead" or "Qualified"
                   select opportunity).ToList();
}
```

It's like everything I read is just slightly touching on what I need, but never quite gets me to a solution. For the project I'm working on, we bring in a very large list of over 1.7K of complex objects from an API. And then, we sort through this list several times on the UI to create a dynamic kanban display. The goal is to run through this massive list and break into smaller lists, asynchronously, so the looping in the HTML doesn't have as much work to do.

**Update: Included Api Call**
Actual API Call within a service class.:

```
public List<Opportunity> GetOpportunities()
{
    {
        OpportunitiesApi opportunitiesApi = new (_connection.CwConfiguration);

        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new ();
        int               pageNumber    = 0;
        bool              areAvailable  = false;

        while (areAvailable == false)
        {
            List<Opportunity> opportunityPage       = opportunitiesApi.GetSalesOpportunities(_settings.ClientId, null, null, null, null, null, pageNumber);
            int               opportunityCount      = opportunityPage.Count;
            if (opportunityCount == 0) areAvailable = true;
            opportunities.AddRange(opportunityPage);
            pageNumber++;
        }

        return opportunities;
    }
}

public async Task<List<Opportunity>> GetOpportunitiesAsync()
{
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = await Task.Run(GetOpportunities);

    return new List<Opportunity>(opportunities);
}
```

How we call on the razor component:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _opportunities = await _opportunityService.GetOpportunitiesAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is `_opportunities`? GetSalesOpportunitiesAsync seems to lack a return statement. I'm also a little bit confused by the loop on WhenAny versus just using WhenAll

Comment: Assuming `_opportunities` is an external database, then you can change `ToList()` to `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: @Gabriel I get the feeling it isn't; I don't think one can use a pattern match expression like `string is "x" or "y"` in eg an EF Where ("An expression tree may not contain an is pattern match operator" .. but not in a position to check atm ?)

Comment: _opportunities is the list of type Opportunity given to us by the API we're calling. And I've tried adding the ToListAsync() but for some reason, I don't have access to that in a razor component.

Comment: Show us the API call; that might be async'able.. But honestly if you're expecting to be able to await something and it be some massive performance boost to processing a block of data you already have in memory I think you might be disappointed ..

Comment: Seems like what you want is Parallelism which is not the same as Asynchronism.  However once you parallelize long running tasks you can use async to await those tasks.  The other  more common use for async is to not block when doing IO (Database, File, Web).

Comment: @juharr That's what I'm looking at now. I'm trying to use the Parallel.ForEach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of asynchronous code. It is only useful when getting data from an external source: a network request, the file system, etc. This is so that the thread can go do other work while waiting for a response, rather than sitting idly. In the context of ASP.NET, this means that your application can handle a higher load of HTTP requests using less threads overall.

If the data is already in memory, then there is no waiting, so asynchronous code isn't needed.

So if `_opportunities` holds data already in memory, then you don't need asynchronous code to access that data.

However, your code that gets the data from your API can be asynchronous.

The Microsoft documentation on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) is very informative. I suggest you read through those articles.

Comment: I have done nothing but read through the documentation for Asynchronous programming by Microsoft for the past two days. It all makes sense when I read it. But then when I actually try to use it, I get unexpected issues.

Comment: @JustinErdmier What is your code that actually gets data from an external source? I suspect it is in `opportunitiesApi.GetSalesOpportunities()`. Is that your code or some external library? Is there a `opportunitiesApi.GetSalesOpportunitiesAsync()`?

Comment: Also, I understand that the data in _opportunities is already in memory. What I'm trying to achieve is improving the performance for the additional looping through that data. As it stands, when you navigate to the page, it gives a blank screen for a solid 15-30 seconds as it prepares the data and builds the view. I understand Blazor is built to do just that, so I want to try and make it faster.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code from the service class that actually calls the API.

Comment: @JustinErdmier Right, I saw that. That's what I was asking about.

Comment: @JustinErdmier Are you sure the delay is in processing the data, or getting the data?

Comment: I see now. Yes, the opportunitiesApi.GetSalesOpportunities() is the provided method for the SDK they provided for their API. Unfortunately, they do not provide an async call.

Comment: What does that do under the hood though; if it's some pre packaged DLL that bangs off a request for some json to some server somewhere then you could async it, but (and at the risk of laboring a point) it wouldn't necessarily help your current situation. Sync is like an office workforce where one person loads the printer with paper, another fetches the paper; if there is no paper the loader sits and does nothing. Async is like a workforce where any employee proactively does anything; no paper means that employee maybe goes and gets the paper. It doesn't make them load the printer any *faster*